# Uncaught reference error for external JS file in html

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

I am trying to use Javascript code I wrote in a separate file with HTML. Am getting uncaught reference error for one of the javascript file. Issue is sporadic. Not occurring always. I am importing fonts in side style.css file. But not all fonts are getting loaded. My main worry is related to uncaught reference error for language.js file. I am thinking some thing wrong related to loading of files. But not sure how to overcome.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Display Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        for (let fontVal of document.fonts.values()) {
            fontVal.load().then((val) => {
                console.log("fontLoaded : " + val.family + " " + val.weight);
            }).catch((err) => {
                console.log("fontLoadingErr : " + err);
            });
        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="client/ClientSocketIo.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Constants.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/audio-led.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/page.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/display.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/language.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        var constants = new Constants();
        var language = new Language();
        var audioLed = new AudioLed(constants);
        var page = new Page(language,audioLed,constants);
        display = new Display(page,language,constants);

        clientSocket = io.connect('http://localhost:39198', {
            transports: ['websocket'],
            'forceNew': true,
            rejectUnauthorized: false,
            reconnection: true,
            reconnectionDelay: 1000,
            reconnectionDelayMax : 1000,
            reconnectionAttempts: 99999
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Content here -->
</body>
</html>
```

I am getting error with language.js file. It is giving error as [2303:2303:0705/174558:INFO:CONSOLE(25)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: Language is not defined", source: http://localhost:39198/index.html (25)
And getting other font loading errors as well.  Below are the logs.

```
[2303:2328:0705/174557:VERBOSE1:logging_network_change_observer.cc(63)] Observed a change to the network IP addresses
[2303:2303:0705/174557:INFO:CONSOLE(11)] "fontLoadingErr : NetworkError: A network error occurred.", source: http://localhost:39198/index.html (11)
[2303:2303:0705/174557:INFO:CONSOLE(11)] "fontLoadingErr : NetworkError: A network error occurred.", source: http://localhost:39198/index.html (11)
[2303:2303:0705/174557:INFO:CONSOLE(11)] "fontLoadingErr : NetworkError: A network error occurred.", source: http://localhost:39198/index.html (11)
[2303:2303:0705/174557:INFO:CONSOLE(11)] "fontLoadingErr : NetworkError: A network error occurred.", source: http://localhost:39198/index.html (11)
[2303:2303:0705/174557:INFO:CONSOLE(11)] "fontLoadingErr : NetworkError: A network error occurred.", source: http://localhost:39198/index.html (11)
[2303:2303:0705/174557:INFO:CONSOLE(11)] "fontLoadingErr : NetworkError: A network error occurred.", source: http://localhost:39198/index.html (11)
[2303:2303:0705/174557:INFO:CONSOLE(11)] "fontLoadingErr : NetworkError: A network error occurred.", source: http://localhost:39198/index.html (11)
[2303:2303:0705/174557:INFO:CONSOLE(11)] "fontLoadingErr : NetworkError: A network error occurred.", source: http://localhost:39198/index.html (11)
[2303:2303:0705/174557:INFO:CONSOLE(11)] "fontLoadingErr : NetworkError: A network error occurred.", source: http://localhost:39198/index.html (11)
[2303:2303:0705/174557:INFO:CONSOLE(11)] "fontLoadingErr : NetworkError: A network error occurred.", source: http://localhost:39198/index.html (11)
[2303:2303:0705/174557:INFO:CONSOLE(11)] "fontLoadingErr : NetworkError: A network error occurred.", source: http://localhost:39198/index.html (11)
[2303:2303:0705/174557:INFO:CONSOLE(11)] "fontLoadingErr : NetworkError: A network error occurred.", source: http://localhost:39198/index.html (11)
[2303:2303:0705/174557:INFO:CONSOLE(11)] "fontLoadingErr : NetworkError: A network error occurred.", source: http://localhost:39198/index.html (11)
[2303:2303:0705/174557:INFO:CONSOLE(11)] "fontLoadingErr : NetworkError: A network error occurred.", source: http://localhost:39198/index.html (11)
[2303:2303:0705/174557:INFO:CONSOLE(11)] "fontLoadingErr : NetworkError: A network error occurred.", source: http://localhost:39198/index.html (11)
**[2303:2303:0705/174558:INFO:CONSOLE(25)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: Language is not defined",** source: http://localhost:39198/index.html (25)
[2303:2328:0705/174559:VERBOSE1:logging_network_change_observer.cc(86)] Observed a network change to state CONNECTION_NONE
[2303:2328:0705/174559:VERBOSE1:logging_network_change_observer.cc(86)] Observed a network change to state CONNECTION_UNKNOWN
[2303:2303:0705/174606:INFO:CONSOLE(9)] "fontLoaded : Source-Han-Sans-SC 500", source: http://localhost:39198/index.html (9)
[2303:2303:0705/174609:INFO:CONSOLE(9)] "fontLoaded : Source-Han-Sans-HC 400", source: http://localhost:39198/index.html (9)
[2303:2303:0705/174612:INFO:CONSOLE(9)] "fontLoaded : Source-Han-Sans-HC 500", source: http://localhost:39198/index.html (9)
[2303:2303:0705/174614:INFO:CONSOLE(9)] "fontLoaded : Source-Han-Sans-SC 400", source: http://localhost:39198/index.html (9)
[2303:2328:0705/174618:VERBOSE1:logging_network_change_observer.cc(63)] Observed a change to the network IP addresses
[2303:2328:0705/174620:VERBOSE1:logging_network_change_observer.cc(86)] Observed a network change to state CONNECTION_NONE
[2303:2328:0705/174620:VERBOSE1:logging_network_change_observer.cc(86)] Observed a network change to state CONNECTION_UNKNOWN
```

Could anyone please explain to me where I am going wrong?

====================================================================
Below is the language.js code

```
"use strict";

(function()
{
    var Language = (function()
    {
        var Language = function ()
        {
            this.m_tagMap = {
                'en-US': {
                    go: "GO",
                    expiry: "CARD<br>EXPIRED",
                    used: "CARD JUST<br>USED"
                },
                /*Mandarin or Simplified Chinese*/
                'cmn': {
                    go: "继续",
                    expiry: "卡已过期",
                    used: "刚用过"
                },
                /*Cantonese or Traditional Chinese*/
                'yue': {
                    go: "繼續",
                    expiry: "卡已過期",
                    used: "剛用過"
                },
                /*Portuguese*/
                'pt': {
                    go: "PROSSEGUIR",
                    expiry: "CARTÃO<br>EXPIRADO",
                    used: "CARTÃO USADO<br>APENAS",
                },
                /*Spanish*/
                'es-ES': {
                    go: "PROCEDER",
                    expiry: "TARJETA<br>VENCIDA",
                    used: "TARJETA RECIÉN<br>USADA"
                }
            };
        };

       Language.prototype.supportedLanguages = function()
       {
           this.languagesSupported = ["en-US", "cmn", "yue", "pt", "es-ES"];
           return this.languagesSupported;
       }

        Language.prototype.getLanguage = function( index )
        {
            var size = Object.keys(this.m_tagMap).length;

            //If index is greater than/equal to length then return en-US 
            if(index >= size)
               return ( Object.keys(this.m_tagMap)[0] );

            //else
            index = index % size;

            return ( Object.keys(this.m_tagMap)[index] );
        };

        Language.prototype.getTagValue = function( tag, language )
        {
            return (this.m_tagMap[language][tag]);
        };

        Language.prototype.numberToCurrency = function( value, language )
        {
            return ( value.toLocaleString( language, { style: "currency", currency: "USD" } ) );
        };

        Language.prototype.getMonthNameFromDateBasedOnLanguage = function(date, language)
        {
            var localeLanguage = language;
            var strmonth = "";
            if(localeLanguage === 'yue')
            {
                var traditionalChineseLangCode = 'zh-Hans-TW'
                var strmonth = date.toLocaleString(traditionalChineseLangCode, { month: 'long'})
            }
            else if(localeLanguage ===  'cmn')
            {
                var simpliedChineseLangCode = 'zh-Hans-CN';
                var strmonth = date.toLocaleString(simpliedChineseLangCode, { month: 'long'})
            }
            else
            {
                strmonth = date.toLocaleString(localeLanguage,{ month: 'short'});
            }
            return strmonth;

        }
        
        Language.prototype.getDate = function( value, language )
        {
                var date =  new Date(value);
                var options = { weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' };
                if(language === "sg-CN") {
                    return date.toLocaleDateString('zh-Hans-CN', options);
                }
                else {
                    return date.toLocaleDateString(language, options);
                }
        };
        Language.prototype.getFontFamily = function(language)
        {
                var fontFamily = "";
                if(language === "en-US")
                {
                   fontFamily = "";
                }
                else if(language === "cmn")
                {
                   fontFamily = "mandarin";
                }
                else if(language === "yue")
                {
                   fontFamily = "cantonese";
                }
                else if(language == "es-ES")
                {
                    fontFamily = "spanish";
                }
                else if(language == "pt")
                {
                    fontFamily = "portuguese";
                }
                else 
                {
                   fontFamily = "";
                }
                return fontFamily;
        };

        return Language;
    }());
    if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && typeof module.exports !== 'undefined')
        module.exports = Language;  // running in nodejs
    else
        window.Language = Language;  // running in browser
}());
```

Comment: it's complaining at the line "var language = new Language()" make sure `Language` is defined here before using the `new` operator. console.log(Language) to check it.

Comment: I have defined Language in below file
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/language.js"></script>
and above code is placed before var language = new Language(); But I am not sure why that error is coming

Comment: maybe it's worth including what is in the language.js file for us to see.

Comment: @cute_programmer, I have added language.js file code.. Kindly have a look

Comment: any help on the above error would be appreciated.

Comment: I tried to import Language.js and it's working I didn't get the same error. what I can recommend is to remove any dependencies except language.js and just create the instance. if you don't get any error then something is overriding it from the other dependencies. do sometinh like this 

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/language.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
           var language = new Language();
   </script>

Comment: I noticed as well that before creating the Langauge instance you create `Constants`. check its source code if it overrides `Language`. that is the only code executed before Language.